# Calculate running total SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

With a stored procedure in SQL Server, I'm trying to calculate running total the following way:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spInsert_Inventory
    (@Brand VARCHAR(50),
     @Series VARCHAR(50),
     @Model VARCHAR(50),
     @Ram INT,
     @HDD INT,
     @Qty INT,
     @Price INT)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Laptops
                   WHERE Brand = @Brand
                     AND Series = @Series
                     AND Model = @Model
                     AND ram = @Ram 
                     AND hdd = @HDD)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @totale INT = 0

        SET @totale = (@Price * @Qty)

        INSERT INTO Laptops 
        VALUES (@Brand, @Series, @Model, @Ram, @HDD, @Qty, @Price, @totale)
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Laptops 
        SET qty = @Qty, 
            Price = @Price,
            Total = ISNULL(Total, 0) + (@Price * @Qty)
        WHERE 
            Brand = @Brand 
            AND Series = @Series
            AND Model = @Model 
            AND ram=@Ram 
            AND hdd = @HDD          
    END 
END
```

Now, when I try insert new record and calculate running total my result is double ..for example if I insert Qty =3 and Price 3 my Total is 18 but this result is not true.

My desired output:

```
Brand Series Model Ram  HDD  Qty  Price  Total
----------------------------------------------
AAA   SAS    DSS   200   25   3     3      9  
BBB   GFG    KHH    50   65   5    20    100
```

When update this row AAA or BBB I want to use running total for updated row

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Try with just `Total=(@Price*@Qty)`

Comment: I'm using SQL  management studio 2014.,  With Total=(@Price*@Qty) I don't have running total when I use update

Comment: You are not incrementing quantity though, is this expected? If Qty was 3 then you update with 3 more it will still say 3 Qty but Total will be 18.

Comment: That's right...

Comment: This is totally unclear.   What do you mean if you "insert Qty =3 and Price 3 my Total is 18"?   Please update your question with a script that fully reproduces the issue, and make it clear what result should be produced instead.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Now it's clearer..When I insert Qty =3 and Price 3 my Total is 18 but I want result 9 ..

Comment: If you don't want 18, then don't add 3*3 to 9 in the else clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this this way.
I would make this process more transactional and more normalized.
Create a table that stores records about inventory.

This would turn adding and removing from inventory into INSERT statements only.
Adding would insert a positive integer of quantity and removing would insert a negative integer of quantity.

Then you can sum up the quantity for any period, and know exactly the inventory you have. Since you will store the price for any transaction on the inventory, you can handle that math any way you want.

This would allow you to derive the table you are creating and its just a math problem at that point.

Comment: Agreed. I can even move it one step further and put all that insert or update logic in the app BL layer and let the DB for what it was make: persistence. Also I can create a log table to track the inventory ins and outs

Answer (score 0):

With a name like `spInsert_Inventory` and code that is essentially doing an `UPSERT` or a `MERGE` (depending which database you use), you probably should be updating `Qty` to `qty=isnull(qty,0)+@Qty` instead of `qty=@Qty`, and `Price` should probably be a weighted average:

```
Price = case when isnull(qty,0)+@Qty = 0
             then @Price
             else (isnull(Total,0)+@Price*@Qty)
                / (isnull(qty,0)+@Qty)
        end
```

Your full update statement would then be something like this:

```
UPDATE Laptops
   set qty=isnull(qty,0)+@Qty
     , Price = case when isnull(qty,0)+@Qty = 0
                    then @Price
                    else (isnull(Total,0)+@Price*@Qty)
                       / (isnull(qty,0)+@Qty)
               end
     , Total=isnull(Total,0)+(@Price*@Qty)
WHERE Brand=@Brand 
    and Series=@Series
    and Model=@Model 
    and ram=@Ram 
    and hdd=@HDD
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't need to increase Qty or Price when i update my **spInsert_Inventory** just need to change a entered numbers and then calculate that numbers  in Total with running total

Answer (score -1):

You are adding to the Total.  What else would you expect?

```
Total=isnull(Total,0)+(@Price*@Qty)
```